# Javascript error in Google Maps API v3 (RefererDeniedMapError)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We were using Google Maps without key and because of our traffic increase we had to create and add the API key in our JS call. But now, when we are calling the JS we are receiving this error:

> RefererDeniedMapError:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#errorcodes

In the documentation we don't see more information related to this error.
With the same API key we don't have any problem to show the map in our other domains, only we have the problem in one.

Playing with the allowed referrers we have discarded problems of configuration and we don't know if maybe our domain could be banned.

The billing information was added too.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is posted [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages), but it's not very descriptive. I suggest you check your credentials in the developer console and make sure you have added the domain which you experience the issue on.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I already do it and the credentials are ok with the allowed domains introduced. We didn't found any information about this error and there is no way to speak with anybody from Google maps :(

Comment: Hi! Is there any news regarding this? I'm facing the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the site your having the issue with? that would help.

Comment: @GusB This page has a list of errors: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages Can you say which error you're getting?

Comment: @GusB Make sure you have the correct domains. If your domain name is like `mydomain.com` then Google recommends to add them like `*.mydomain.com/*`.

Comment: @GusB I believe the answer from Thor is more relevant and suitable. And he made solutions.

Answer (score 7):

I’ve found an URL to your website in google’s thread and I was able to reproduce this problem locally. I’ve just added your host name in hosts file and addressed it to localhost. I’ve got the same error. It’s definitely domain name related problem.

I was able to make map works only using IP and path to a map page, instead of domain name, like:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>A page where should be a map</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <iframe src='http://127.0.0.1/mapa.html'></iframe>
     </body>
   </html>
```

You could try to disable IP to domain name redirection (as you have now), and use your IP in the example above. It’s not a pure solution, but at least you can have a map on your website.

Answer (score 6):

> Javascript error in Google Maps API v3 (**RefererDeniedMapError**)

After a detailed research into your issue that you are currently facing,i have come across with some possible answers to your question apart from the other answers.

There are two types of [Referer errors](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages) :

1. RefererNotAllowedMapError

   The current URL loading the Google Maps JavaScript API has not been
   added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer
   settings of your [API key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys) on Google Cloud Console.
2. **RefererDeniedMapError**

   Your request has not been completed. You may be able to find the
   more details about the error in the [**Google Cloud Console**](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https://console.developers.google.com/#identifier)(please have a look).

> We were using Google Maps without key and because of our traffic
>   increase we had to create......

1. What are the usage limits for the Google Maps **JavaScript API v3**?
2. What are the usage limits for the Google Earth API?

Requests that constitute page views are applied against the total number of page views purchased with your Google Maps API for Work license. When this limit is reached, you will need to renew your license promptly.

Please read more limitations [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#js_usage_limits)

> Error message that you are facing may be a clear indication that you
>   have crossed any limitations ,and that would be hard to guess at this
>   point from this end as detailed analysis and configuration report from
>   your account(console) is required.

Keep Checking the limitations , errors in your cloud console.

As a final call you can contact the [**paid support**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/support) from google.

Find More references below :

1. [Google terms](http://www.google.co.in/help/terms_maps.html)
2. [Keys FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem)
3. [SO post on multiple APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138091/use-multiple-google-maps-api-keys-for-same-server)

Hope that would be useful ..
Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: I posted that solution (IP instead of domain name) into the google thread 3 days ago. Then I posted it here. It's a second time for today, when I saw a link to my solution in the google thread here.

Comment: `The current URL loading the Google Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed referrers. ` is it mean we have to add each url of the domain where we have map?