# GMaps RefererDeniedMapError - JS Browser key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Since last week, we have been facing an issue related to the maps loading in our customer website.
Website pages' and domains are:

http://eduscopio.it/percorso-studenti-scelta-scuola-superiore (click on the search icon to jump to the map slide)

http://lavoro.eduscopio.it/percorso-studenti-scelta-scuola-superiore (click on the search icon to jump to the map slide)

The javascript console shows us "js?key=:32 Google Maps API error: RefererDeniedMapError".

After reading the documentation, and many topics on forum and stackoverflow, we tried to perform these operations in order to try get the map working again:

- we added the api key (the website wasn't using it)
- we rebuilt part of the layout to allow the Google logo and TOS to be clickable and viewable (they where partly hidden or not clickable due to an overlay)
- we restricted domains and allowed the use of api key to some certain domains
- we tried to renew the api key many times

The websiste is public and the usage is free without any sort of subscription. According to the API console, we didn't reach the quota limit.
On the API console there are no more details provided in regards to the error an no one between us has been contacted via e-mail

Thank you in advance, best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 error: RefererDeniedMapError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317834/google-maps-api-v3-error-refererdeniedmaperror)

Comment: I believe you were able to solve this issue via https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10091