# using multiple Google Map Api Keys

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

Can I use more than one google maps API key in the same app?
I'd like to realize following two features on my app:

1. To load GoogleMap by using Google Maps Android API, and search routes by Google Maps JavaScript API.
2. To get multiple routes at high speed by using multiple Google Maps JavaScript API Keys. If one key, OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error will occur when DirectionsService.route() is called.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: you might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138091/use-multiple-google-maps-api-keys-for-same-server

Comment: Thank you  Arachnid Hivemind.
I've read this, but the best answer of this question was edited over two years ago, the official document by Google has seemed to change after this answer.
I can't find  any documents that profess to forbid to get or use multiple API Keys.
Sorry.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I doubt that Google allows for the usage of multiple API keys now as it just adds another step to avoiding their rate limits. I also looked for the info that you want but cant find it but I wouldn't recommend implementing it that way

Comment: Yes, I doubt it too. But Google doesn't seem to announce about it in detail, according to its documents.

Answer (score 0):

The limits for requested services by using the maps-Javascript-API apply to the user, not the the project.

So the usage of multiple keys wouldn't change any anything, because the user(IP of the client) is still the same.

Comment: Thank you Dr.Molle.
According to your answer, I can't realize the feature 2 by multiple Javascript API Keys.
I understand.

Comment: the android-API-key has to be used for android-apps, not for implementations of the Javascript-API on a webpage

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't both api in the same app?
My app is a kind of navigation app.
I will use Google Maps Android API on server-side, and Javascript-API on client-side.I'd like to use Javascript-API only for getting the data of routes.Android API will be used to load map, get current position by GPS and display routes on map.

Comment: a website isn't a android-app, and a server also isn't a android-app. For loading the Javasript-API(or other APIs) on client-side(in a webbrowser) use a browser-key, for serverside-requests from a webpage use a server-key, and for apps use a iOs/android-key

Comment: Sorry for not explaining enough.I'll use android-key(Google Maps Android API) for loading map and browser-key(Google Maps JavaScript API) for getting data by dummy html file.This html exists only for calling javascript-function in which directions service is called.