# Use multiple Google Map Account for websites on the same server

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I have one real website using google map and It is binded with several domains. Each domain serves for a separated group of client.

Google map announces new policy updates that apply from 11th june 2018 that decrease free limit usage from 25K map loads per day to 28K map load per month

My questions is **Can I use map api key which generated from separated google account to increase free usage ?**

I have read this question carefully [use multiple Google Maps API Keys for same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138091/use-multiple-google-maps-api-keys-for-same-server)

But link seems broken and I can't find relevant information as answer on that question or some other questions too

In my case, although my sites have the same code based and IP, however they works like different sites on shared hosts. One more thing, Google assigns free usage based on account (not google map key) so I think I can use multiple account to increase limit

So can I do this ? I don't want to break Google rules and I appreciate for any comment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding

Comment: @geocodezip thank for your vote and comment. I got your point, this question is not really related coding. However, I ask for a solution to fit new google api rule which is still a term of programming and can be useful for others in the future. So I ask it on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not since is against Google terms, please check section 3.2.4.e in this link https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#16-limitation-of-liability.

> No Circumventing Fees.  Customer will not circumvent the applicable Fees. For example, Customer will not create multiple billing accounts or Projects to avoid incurring Fees; prevent Google from accurately calculating Customer’s Service usage levels; abuse any free Service quotas; or offer access to the Services under a “time-sharing” or “service bureau” model.

Comment: In fact, I still think there is a chance for my case because my server works like shared host with multiple websites and Google may accept separated account for each website. However, your answer is the best because It give me official information. Real result will depend on how google implement 3.2.4 term in detail. Thank for your answer

Comment: indeed you can use multiple accounts as long as you do not circumvent fees, thanks to you as well

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's against the rules:
Google Maps guy said here, that it's OK https://twitter.com/GMapsPlatform/status/1001061642363461633

Comment: Thank for your contribution. Based on your link, one google account can create multiple billing account, that also means we may take more than one $200 free quotas. Therefore if we have multiple websites, each one may take its own $200 and no need to share with others in the same one google account. I hope that is true

Comment: @BùiĐứcKhánh - this is true, but you need a different payment card for each billing account, so if you have 10 billing accounts you need 10 different credit cards. I currently have 4.